# Ansible how to get access to the main level roles dir ? so i can include generic tasks from any playbook?

Tags: ansible

i have role which i try to get using includ_role 
now i have this file structure

```
.
├── foo_A
│   └── roles
│       ├── foo_deploy
├── foo_B
│   └── roles
│       ├── db_foo
│       │   └── tasks
├── foo_C
│   └── roles
│       ├── package_deploy
│       │   ├── defaults
│       │   ├── files
│       │   └── tasks
│       │       └── main.yml       
├── group_vars
└── roles
    └── utilities
        ├── defaults
        ├── files
        ├── handlers
        ├── meta
        ├── tasks
            └── dpackage.yml 
        ├── templates
        └── vars
```

I'm calling the include_role with the utilities name from main.yml
but I'm getting an error that that main level role is not units search paths

```
ERROR! the role 'utilities' was not found in /home/ec2-user/ansible/foo_C/roles:/home/ec2-user/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles:/home/ec2-user/ansible/foo_C

The error appears to be in '/home/ec2-user/ansible/foo_C/roles/package_deploy/tasks/main.yml': line 78, column 11, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  include_role:
    name: utilities
          ^ here
```

how can i get access to the main roles dir under : /home/ec2-user/ansible

Comment: Since your roles are in non default roles location, you have to tweak the roles search path: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-search-path

Comment: thanks i can see several config params, which one ADD to the existing ansible roles path? not substitute

Comment: This is the corresponding line in ansible.cfg => https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/ansible.cfg#L67

Comment: greate thanks allot